# Editing an excel with Openpyxl creates a faulty file but nothing is wrong inside

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I want to create a report with a dataframe I paste into an existing excel file. I take a template, save it with a new name, open this document and paste a dataframe into an existing, but empty, sheet. Apart from this sheet, there is another one that has a pivot table that summarizes the dataframe data in the manner that I want (the use of the template is necessary, as pasting pandas pivot tables is not a possibility).

When I open the newly created document in excel, an alert comes up that says content was lost. When I press yes to recover it, the document shows up perfectly and nothing is wrong with it. What can I do so this alert does not show up?
[excel alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15n6I.png)

I have seen solutions involving installing older versions of Openpyxl (I currently have version 3.1.4), but cannot do it as I have no permits for it.

This is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import shutil

data = {
    'Column1': ['Dato1', 'Dato2', 'Dato3'],
    'Column2': ['Dato4', 'Dato5', 'Dato6'],
    'Column3': ['Dato7', 'Dato8', 'Dato9']
}

df_filtrado = pd.DataFrame(data)

template_path = 'template.xlsx'
file_name = 'new_test.xlsx'  
shutil.copyfile(template_path, nombre_archivo)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl', mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists='replace')
df_filtrado.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False)
writer.save()
```

I know the issue comes from the `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(...` line, as testing the code with no changes in the document (just opening and closing the excel) still gives the same issue.
I have tried to style the document to see if that fixes the problem, but there was no change:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles import Font
import pandas as pd
import shutil

data = {
    'Column1': ['Dato1', 'Dato2', 'Dato3'],
    'Column2': ['Dato4', 'Dato5', 'Dato6'],
    'Column3': ['Dato7', 'Dato8', 'Dato9']
}

df_filtrado = pd.DataFrame(data)

template_path = 'template.xlsx'
file_name = 'new_test.xlsx'  
wb = load_workbook(template_path)
fontStyle = Font(name="Calibri", size=12, color=colors.BLACK)
sheet = wb.active
sheet['A1'].font = fontStyle
wb.save(file_name)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl', mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists='replace')
sheet = wb.active
sheet['A1'].font = fontStyle
df_filtrado.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Datos', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Your code (both) should work but you will want to change `writer.save()` to `writer.close()` Or use a Context Manager for the writer

Comment: The alert probably refers to something within the pivot table that has changed without the pivot table being changed.

Comment: @moken, no change when I try with `writer.close()`. @Charlie Clark, I have tried deleting the pivot table from the template to see if the issue comes from that, but no, the code still gives the same issue.

Comment: Do you have the latest Pandas installed? I'm guessing Openpyxl is the latest but not sure its up to 3.1.4 yet. Are there any errors when the code is run? If `writer.save` does not return an error, you might be running an older release of Pandas.